# How to set the size of a JFrame through Spring setter injection?

Tags: java, spring, swing

I am trying to initialize a JFrame using Spring. The Frame showed up, until I set the size property (MainFrame simply extends JFrame).

```
<bean id="mainFrame" class="package.MainFrame" init-method="init" >
    <property name="title" value="Setting the title works ..." />
    <property name="size">
        <bean class="java.awt.Dimension" >
            <constructor-arg value="600" />
            <constructor-arg value="800" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The error message I get is:

```
NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'size' of bean class [package.MainFrame]: Bean property 'size' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

The JFrame class has a setter setSize(Dimension) and a getter getSize(Dimension). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If its a good practice or not, shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame.setSize` has two overloaded versions: `setSize(int, int)` and `setSize(java.awt.Dimension)`. So spring guesses that size is not bean property.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="frame" class="javax.swing.JFrame">
        <property name="title" value="First swing-spring project"/>
                <property name="size"> 
            <bean class="java.awt.Dimension">
                <constructor-arg value="300"/>
                <constructor-arg value="400"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultCloseOperation" value="3"/>
        <property name="visible" value="true"/>

    </bean>
```